# 相対インポートを行おうとするとエラーが発生する

Tags: python

## 状況

main.pyからsub1.pyを明示的な相対インポートで呼び出そうとすると、ImportErrorが発生してしまいます。

なぜsubパッケージの相対インポートは失敗してしまうのでしょうか？

### 実行内容

```
$ python3 main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .sub import sub1
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

### フォルダ構成

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── sub
    ├── __init__.py
    └── sub1.py
```

### ファイル

main.py

```py
from .sub import sub1

sub1.greet()
```

sub1.py

```py
def greet():
    print('this is sub1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記で良いかと思います。

`from sub import sub1`

Answer (score 0):

`from .sub import sub1`のような明示的な相対インポートを使いたいときには、親ディレクトリを作る必要があるようです。

今回の例では親ディレクトリは存在していないため、`main.py`からsubパッケージを呼び出す方法としては、`from sub import sub1`という絶対インポート方式での呼び方が適切。